# Querying SQLite Database for specific cell

Tags: python, database, sqlite

Forgive me if this is a basic question, I'm learning on my own and having some trouble.  I have built a database with SQLite and am trying to write something that can display the 'description' of an entry when the name is entered into an entry box.

```
record_id = call_field.get()
# Query the database
c.execute("SELECT name, abbr, description FROM TQ_QUICKTEXT WHERE name =" + record_id)
records = c.fetchall()

# Loop through results
for record in records:
    display.insert(1.0, record[2])
```

When I type the name of the entry that has been put into the database, an error is returned saying there is no column with that name.  However, when I type the actual word 'name' into the entry box and run the function every single description entry is returned.  If someone wouldn't mind pointing out where I've made mistakes it would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `SELECT` statement that is executed currently looks like this:
`SELECT name, abbr, description FROM TQ_QUICKTEXT WHERE name = something` (where `something` is the value of `record_id`)

Because there are no quotes around the value of `record_id`, it thinks it is a column name, not text. This is why when you try the name of a record, you get an error because that is not a column name, but `name` works, because it is the name of a column.
Adding quotes will fix the problem, but the database is vulnerable to SQL injection.
It is good security practise to parameterise SQL queries to prevent this. This is done by using `?` in place of parameters and then passing a tuple of parameters to the execute function. This protects you from SQL injection.
After these changes, the `c.execute` statment should look like this:
`c.execute("SELECT name, abbr, description FROM TQ_QUICKTEXT WHERE name = ?", (record_id,))`

Comment: Hi Henry.  This works perfectly, thank you so much for taking the time to help me out!

Comment: I'm glad I could help :)